# What's the difference between an Entity constraint and an association?

Tags: associations, entity, constraints, oracle-adf

In Oracle ADF, you can create a validation rule (Key Exists) that checks the existence of a key in another entity attribute, but you must have an association defined to the destination entity.

Also, it is possible to define an entity constraint that references another entity's attribute, but it only requires the referenced attribute to be a primary key.

Effectively, how are they any different from each other?

Is it an abundance of choice, or is there an intrinsic difference that I should learn about?

Answer (score 0):

Having an association allows you to not just do validation but also access one EO from the other, and manage the way data in this master-detail relationship is inserted into the database. (read about composite associations for more).